# Is there any function in python which can perform the inverse of numpy.repeat function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

For example

```
x = np.repeat(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), 2, axis=1)
```

gives you

```
x = array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
          [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

but is there something which can perform

```
 x = np.*inverse_repeat*(np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2],[3, 3, 4, 4]]), axis=1)
```

and gives you

```
x = array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

Comment: How general of a `repeat` are you talking about?  Do you know the repeat parameters ahead of time?  A single number repeat on a known axis is easy.  But repeat can use a different number for each element.

Comment: @hpaulj As I said in the question, I want the exact inverse of the np.repeat function. i.e. fixed number of repeats

Comment: See my answer for more details on why I asked this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular slicing should work. For the axis you want to *inverse* repeat, use `::number_of_repetitions`

```
x = np.repeat(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), 4, axis=0)
x[::4, :]  # axis=0
Out: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

x = np.repeat(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), 3, axis=1)

x[:,::3]  # axis=1
Out: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])


x = np.repeat(np.array([[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]]), 5, axis=2)
x[:,:,::5]  # axis=2
Out: 
array([[[1],
        [2]],

       [[3],
        [4]]])
```

Comment: note that the slicing syntax does not allow us to easily programmatically express the axis to de-repeat over though

Answer (score 2):

This should work, and has the exact same signature as np.repeat:

```
def inverse_repeat(a, repeats, axis):
    if isinstance(repeats, int):
        indices = np.arange(a.shape[axis] / repeats, dtype=np.int) * repeats
    else:  # assume array_like of int
        indices = np.cumsum(repeats) - 1
    return a.take(indices, axis)
```

Edit: added support for per-item repeats as well, analogous to np.repeat

Comment: Nice application of `take` - easier than constructing a multiaxis slicing tuple.

Comment: yeah; I learned about take quite late in my numpy career, and I cringe every time I look back at my old code that tries to programmatically act on a given axis

Comment: This doesn't work if repeats has 0 in it.

Answer (score 1):

For the case where we know the axis and the repeat - and the repeat is a scalar (same value for all elements) we can construct a slicing index like this:

```
In [1117]: a=np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2],[3, 3, 4, 4]])
In [1118]: axis=1; repeats=2

In [1119]: ind=[slice(None)]*a.ndim
In [1120]: ind[axis]=slice(None,None,a.shape[axis]//repeats)
In [1121]: ind
Out[1121]: [slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, 2)]
In [1122]: a[ind]
Out[1122]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

`@Eelco's` use of `take` makes it easier to focus on one axis, but requires a list of indices, not a slice.

But `repeat` does allow for differing repeat counts.

```
In [1127]: np.repeat(a1,[2,3],axis=1)
Out[1127]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Knowing `axis=1` and `repeats=[2,3]` we should be able construct the right `take` indexing (probably with `cumsum`).  Slicing won't work.

But if we only know the axis, and the repeats are unknown then we probably need some sort of `unique` or `set` operation as in `@redratear's` answer.

```
In [1128]: a2=np.repeat(a1,[2,3],axis=1)
In [1129]: y=[list(set(c)) for c in a2]
In [1130]: y
Out[1130]: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

A `take` solution with list `repeats`.  This should select the last of each repeated block:

```
In [1132]: np.take(a2,np.cumsum([2,3])-1,axis=1)
Out[1132]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

A deleted answer uses `unique`; here's my row by row use of `unique`

```
In [1136]: np.array([np.unique(row) for row in a2])
Out[1136]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

`unique` is better than `set` for this use since it maintains element order.  There's another problem with `unique` (or set) - what if the original had repeated values, e.g. `[[1,2,1,3],[3,3,4,1]]`.

Here is a case where it would be difficult to deduce the repeat pattern from the result.  I'd have to look at all the rows first.

```
In [1169]: a=np.array([[2,1,1,3],[3,3,2,1]])
In [1170]: a1=np.repeat(a,[2,1,3,4], axis=1)
In [1171]: a1
Out[1171]: 
array([[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

But `cumsum` on a known repeat solves it nicely:

```
In [1172]: ind=np.cumsum([2,1,3,4])-1
In [1173]: ind
Out[1173]: array([1, 2, 5, 9], dtype=int32)
In [1174]: np.take(a1,ind,axis=1)
Out[1174]: 
array([[2, 1, 1, 3],
       [3, 3, 2, 1]])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.repeat(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), 2, axis=1)
>>> y=[list(set(c)) for c in x] #This part remove duplicates for each array in tuple. So this will not work for x = np.repeat(np.array([[1,1],[3,3]]), 2, axis=1)=[[1,1,1,1],[3,3,3,3]. Result will be [[1],[3]]
>>> print y
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

You dont need know to axis and repeat amount...

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Why are you being picky about format of this answer, but not the others?  In a general repeat case some sort of `set` or `unique` may be required.  Reverting to a list comprehension in `numpy` is discouraged, but sometimes required.

Comment: Ok @TobySpeight I wil do whatever you want. Sorry for my mistakes becouse i am new as member. I dont know general rules.

Comment: @hpaul - only because this was the only answer presented to me in Review.  FWIW, I wasn't a downvoter.